# Grails 1.3.7 to 2.2.0 upgrade

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I'm new to grails, but have to support a project on it. After upgrade i can't start my grails app, getting this error all the time. Grails 2.2.0, spring-security-core 2.0 RC1

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader
Error initializing the application: No such property: /j_spring_security_check for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultBeanConfiguration
Message: No such property: /j_spring_security_check for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultBeanConfiguration
Line | Method
->> 1077 | doCall                    in SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure16
|    252 | doCall                    in SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure2
|    757 | invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder
|    584 | beans                     in     ''
|    527 | invokeMethod . . . . . .  in     ''
|    262 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Where could i look for reason of this error?

Comment: Not sure why you're targeting v2.2.0, but going with that:  I've found that migrating apps from v1.x to v2.x isn't trivial.   Mostly, I start a new app in the new version, get the plugins I want working, then migrate my Controllers, Domains, Services etc. fixing what's wrong after each step.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. If you are new to Grails, don't start with an upgrade unless you really really have to. If you still are going to upgrade, I believe the approach described is the best and detailed in Burt Beckwith's book on Grails. Also verify that all plugins that are being used are compatible with the new version.

Comment: @wwwclaes plugins are compatible (at least they are marked as compatible). I really have to upgrade. And thanks for the book.

Comment: Ok. Good luck and I'll try to look for further questions here on SO :-) I upgraded from 1.3.7 to 2.3.11 recently and it's not a fun thing to do. Another advice might be to use diff tools a lot, create empty projects of both versions to see out-of-the-box changes in config files etc and use that as guidance when you move over changes from your project to the new version. Do it slow and thoroughly, it will be worth it.

Comment: I found that when I upgraded my apps from 1.3 to 2.x, the hardest part (apart from some app-specific stubborn plugins) was the testing. There is a dramatic change in the testing framework from grails 1.x to grails 2.x